# Using 'not' in a 'for-loop statement'

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

1. Why is not possible to use a `not` in a `for` statement?
   Assuming that both `object` and `list` are *iterable*
2. If you can't do that is there another way around?

Here is an example, but *"obviously"* a syntax error:

```
tree = ["Wood", "Plank", "Apples", "Monkey"]

plant = ["Flower", "Plank", "Rose"]

for plant not in tree:
    # Do something
    pass 
else:
    # Do other stuff
    pass
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: is `objects` another list ?

Comment: That's correct. I had modifyed it now!

Comment: Are you trying to loop over everything not in the list? Or are you trying to loop over the negations of the elements of the list? Or are you trying to negate each element of the list in place? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Short answer, you can't...`for` is an iterator statement, you probably meant `if`

Comment: Are you trying to loop over every element of `objects` that isn't in `list`?

Comment: I'm trying to see what objects that are not in the list and print them. Yes sorry for these mistake

Comment: Do you mean to iterate over list items except a few?

Comment: @ShashankGupta Gupta if I used ´if´ it would only print one item not in list

Comment: You can't call a function "123" btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way, using sets and assuming that both `objects` and `list` are iterable:

```
for x in set(objects).difference(lst):
    # do something
```

First of all, you should not call a variable `list`, that'll clash with a built-in name. Now the explanation: the expression `set(objects).difference(lst)` performs a [set difference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference), for example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
objects = [1, 2, 5, 6]
set(objects).difference(lst)
=> set([5, 6])
```

As you can see, we found the elements in `objects` that are not in the list.

Comment: +1 -- This is nice. Note that if you want to retain duplicates in `objects` that are not in `list`, this would need to be modified.

Comment: This answer could use more explanation; the OP isn't likely to have the background knowledge to understand what's going on.

Comment: No need to convert both to a `set` use... `for x in set(objects).difference(list)` or whatever way around the OP wants it

Comment: @user2357112 ok, added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

If `objects` and `list` are two lists, and you want to iterate over every element of `objects` that isn't in `list`, you want the following:

```
for object in objects:
    if object not in list:
        do_whatever_with(object)
```

This loops over everything in `objects` and only processes the ones that aren't in `list`. Note that this won't be very efficient; you could make a set out of `list` for efficient `in` checking:

```
s = set(list)
for object in objects:
    if object not in s:
        do_whatever_with(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing a couple of things.  The `for` loop is used to iterate over sequences (lists, tuples, characters of a string, sets, etc).  The `not` operator reverses boolean values.  Some examples:

```
>>> items = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
>>> for item in items:
...   print item
...
s1
s2
s3
>>> # Checking whether an item is in a list.
... print 's1' in items
True
>>> print 's4' in items
False
>>>
>>> # Negating
... print 's1' not in items
False
>>> print 's4' not in items
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to iterate over a list except few:

```
original = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
to_exclude = ["b","e"]
for item [item for item in orginal if not item in to_exclude]: print item
```

Produces:

```
a
c
d
```

Comment: `if item not in to_exclude` would be more Pythonic

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to achieve what you want:

```
 list_i_have = [1, 2, 4]  
 list_to_compare = [2, 4, 6, 7]

 for l in list_i_have:
     if l not in list_to_compare:
         do_something()
     else:
         do_another_thing()
```

Foreach item in the list you have, you can have a exclude list to check it is inside of list_to_compare.

You can also achieve this with list comprehension:

```
["it is inside the list" if x in (3, 4, 5) else "it is not" for x in (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension combined with inline if:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> objects = [1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> [i for i in objects if i not in lst]
[5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

And another way:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
for obj in ifilterfalse(set(to_exclude).__contains__, objects):
    # do something
```